# JavaFX when will be available for Linux world? Will Oracle make JavaFX like Flash policy to make Linux developers impossible to get it?

Tags: java, linux, flash, javafx, javafx-2

I am looking for JavaFX under Linux Ubuntu/Fedora/OpenSuse/Gentoo/TinycoreLinux/MicrocoreLinux

But none of the OS have a single **JavaFX** latest coding emulators, it will be too late as Linux developers to learn it if it arrives after 10 year or even after few years. Because its already available only for Windows users. Not everyone is wiling to switch to Windows because of many other reasons involved.Do we have to force ourselves only to have JavaFX buy Windows PC? (its again Microsoft behind?)

So my question is, How can i get the JavaFX under Linux? (latest version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's in the FAQ](http://javafx.com/faq/#5):

> **What operating systems are supported by JavaFX?**
>
> JavaFX 2.0 will be fully supported on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of
> Microsoft Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7. Early Access
> versions of JavaFX 2.x for Mac OS and Linux will be made available at
> a later date, but support for these platforms will not be included as
> part of the JavaFX 2.0 final release.

Updated [JavaFX roadmap](http://javafx.com/roadmap/) on oct 13 2011:

> **JavaFX for Linux**
>
> JavaFX will be officially tested and supported on Ubuntu—the most popular Linux distribution on desktop PCs—but is expected to run 'as is' with other Linux distributions. JavaFX for Linux is planned for release in the end of 2012.
>
> **JavaFX for Mac OS X**
>
> JavaFX 2.0 for Mac OS X, which has been available since February 2011 to a limited number of participants, is now available for download as a Developer Preview. While this beta version can be currently tested on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (v 10.6) with Apple's implementation of Java SE 6, the GA1 version will be supported on only Mac OS X Lion (v 10.7) with Oracle's implementation of Java SE 7 for Mac OS X.

Comment: Thank you. I have the impression that its very tricky again. Because its dragging Linux/Mac users to try Windows. I will not use it, i will go for Qt/Qml.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX 2.1 Developers preview for Linux was released today: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html